# How to authenticate register route in Laravel 8 Jetstream?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to disable access to register route without login in laravel 8. I am using laravel jetstream with livewire.
Here is code in routes\web.php. I have not changed anything in route file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: if they are logged in why would they need to register?

Comment: I want only authenticated users only to permit to create new users.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Care to share?

Answer (score 1):

To disable registration go to config/fortify.php and comment out Features::registration().

```
'features' => [ 
    //Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication(), 
],
```

Answer (score 0):

it work with Fortify  you can control its appearance  in

```
 `config/fortify.php    Features::registration(),
```

you can customize the register logic validation ... from `App\Actions\Fortify CreatesNewUsers`